# how to upload and place my branding font into hosting service ???

Tags: css, fonts, hosting, web-hosting

i have a problem to host our branding font and access it online

please i need the steps to host this font on HostGator and how can get the url from our hosting service and access it in CSS3 using @import
how this process take place?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you want to use your custom font.

Steps are given below:

- You have convert your ttf file to web font (you can do it using https://transfonter.org )
- After converting .ttf file to web font you need to upload those files to your server

that's it..

Now you can share or use that font file to your website.

Hope! this will help you.
Thanks